# Decidability of the surjectivity of any given function in $\mathsf{ZFC}$

Tags: set-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two non-empty sets and let $f:X\to Y$ be an arbitrary function. Let $\mathsf P$ be the statement that $f$ is surjective. That is, $$\mathsf P\equiv[\forall y\in Y\,\exists x\in X:y=f(x)].$$ My question is, is $\mathsf P$ always decidable in $\textsf{ZFC}$? Formally speaking, it is true that precisely one of $\textsf{ZFC}+\mathsf P$ and $\textsf{ZFC}+\neg\mathsf P$ is consistent?

Comment: Let $a$ be the number which is $1$ if the cardinal of the continuous is $\aleph_1$ and zero other wise, and consider the set $X=\{0,a\}$. Is the function $f:\{0\}\to X$ which maps $0$ to $0$ surjective?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Fair enough. Although it feels like defining the set $X$ this way (that is, in form of an undecidable conditional) is somehow “cheating.” Is there a neat way to formalize an additional, intuitive requirement that the elements of the set $X$ and $Y$ be “decidably known?”

Comment: @triple_sec : but you can define a function $f : P( \Bbb R) \to \{0,1,2,3\}$ such that : $f(A) = 0$ if $A$ is finite,  $f(A) = 1$ if $A$ is in bijection with $\Bbb N$,  $f(A) = 2$ if $A$ is in bijection with $\Bbb R$, and $f(A) = 3$ if none of the above.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing two things.

1. Consistency is a syntactic notion. It means that a list of axioms does not prove a sentence and its negation.
2. Specific function, namely semantics and particular models and objects.

If your function is definable by a formula which is provably a function, then the question on whether or not we can augment $\sf ZFC$ by the statement that this function is onto $Y$ or not is meaningful (and this also assumes that $Y$ is definable).

On the other hand, if the function is not definable, then asking about consistency is all wrong. Because it's not even a part of the language.

Long story short, it is true that if $F$ is a function, then in classical logic either $F$ is onto $Y$ or not. But stating this in the language requires that everything involve is definable. But it is provable, regardless, that $F$ is either onto $Y$ or not. Now you can use the Law of Excluded Middle, and find it from within.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance—my knowledge about advanced set theory is very limited, and I’m probably at odds with using the terminology correctly. I need to, and will, think more about your illuminating answer.